# Remote desktop through firewall and proxy

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access

Is there anyway I can remote my computer at home from another location (work) where the only way I can access the internet is through an http proxy?

tl;dr Previously I was using RD Gateway and it worked pretty well, I didn't have to install anything in the client. However, my ISP has recently blocked port 443 and 80. After some investigation, I determined that our proxy also allowed communications on port 8080 (I was able to open a site I hosted on that port) so I figured maybe I can change the RD gateway port from 443 to 8080. But after some digging and days of troubleshooting, its seems like its not possible. and that brings me here.

Is there any other way I can remote my computer through an http proxy, preferably without installing additional software on the client? I don't really care how a ugly hack it might be. or maybe some web app I can install that will function like RD using a browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the port on which your computer listens to RDP connections (so you can use 8080) :

Start Registry Editor.
Locate and then click the following registry subkey:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TerminalServer\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\PortNumber
On the Edit menu, click Modify, and then click Decimal.
Type the new port number, and then click OK.
Quit Registry Editor.
Restart the computer.

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't work over http proxy.

Comment: Ah, I didn't read carefully enough. If you can use IE at work, you could try with [Remote Desktop Web Connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383019%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: you shouldn't allow remote desktop directly from the web.  There are several known exploits if you are not upto date with patches and likely to be others.  It is better to do things like this through a VPN or SSH tunnel

Answer (score 0):

I know you mentioned without installing additional software on the client, but you said it's only a preference.  If you can stomach it you could try logmein which is free and accessible from a web browser.